# Encountering Segmentation Fault When Calling log2 Function in ARM64 Assembly Using Clang on M1 Mac

Tags: c, arm64

I am currently working with assembly code on an M1 Mac (ARM64 architecture) and I am trying to call the log2 function from the math library (lm). I am using Clang for compiling the code.

Here is a snippet of my assembly code:

```
ldr s0, [sp, #224]
bl _log2
str s0, [sp, #288]
```

I am compiling and linking the program using the following Python code:

```
print(subprocess.run(["as","-arch", "arm64", "-o", "kernel.o"], input=prg.encode('utf-8')))
print(subprocess.run(["clang","-target", "arm64-apple-darwin" "-lm", "-shared", "kernel.o", "-o", fn]))
```

Upon running my program, I am encountering a segmentation fault. I have looked through the Apple ARM64 documentation, and from what I understand, it seems like the function might be attempting to retrieve the argument for log2 from the stack. However, I was under the impression that single-input functions would utilize the s0 register for arguments.

I am unsure about the source of this issue and any insights would be greatly appreciated. Is there a difference in the convention for passing arguments to functions in the ARM64 architecture that I might be missing? Or could there be a problem in the way I am compiling or linking the program?

Comment: Why don't you try to call it in C and then disassemble the code to see how it's doing it?

Comment: @Blindy or compile directly to assembly language with the `-S` option.

Comment: `s0` is a `float` sized register, but `log2(x)` takes and returns a `double` (`d0` register). `log2f(x)` takes and returns a `float` (`s0` register). Also, you need to conform to the [AArch64 Procedure Call Standard](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/main/aapcs64/aapcs64.rst) and [Writing ARM64 code for Apple platforms](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/writing-arm64-code-for-apple-platforms). (Note that `s0` and `d0` are different views of the `v0` register.)

Comment: @IanAbbott: The s0 vs d0 issue is definitely a bug, but couldn't cause a segfault; you would just get log2 of the value in d0 and it wouldn't be what you wanted.

Comment: The `log2` function most definitely takes and returns its arguments in registers (d0), not on the stack.  I just tested to confirm.  So I think your diagnosis is mistaken, and your bug is somewhere else.  To get further we will need a [mcve].

Comment: @NateEldredge True s0 vs d0 wouldn't cause a segfault. Not following the ABI documented in the links I provided can cause a segfault, but as you wrote, we will need a [mcve].

Comment: @IanAbbott: Yes, because other than s0 versus d0, the example here *does* follow the ABI.  (Provided that `x30` is being saved and restored - if not then that could be the issue.)